# escape special characters in stored procedure variables

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, escaping

I've made a stored procedure to get practice with cursors, I've a problem with special characters, for instance, if last_name contains a single quote, I've got an error, I need to escape it in some way, how could I do that? I don't know which special characters are contained in these fields, I've tried with QUOTENAME(d.last_name) but it didn't work

```
CREATE OR alter PROCEDURE list_employees
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE cursore CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT TOP(20) d.id, d.first_name, d.last_name, cd.contact
          FROM employees d 
          JOIN contacts cd ON cd.fk_employee= d.id
          ORDER BY d.id;
    DECLARE @id_employee VARCHAR(36);
    DECLARE @first_name VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @last_name VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @contact VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE @insert_statement varchar(1000);
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.list_employees', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
       BEGIN
          DROP TABLE dbo.list_employees; 
       END
    OPEN cursore;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursore INTO @id_employee , @first_name , @cognome, @contatto ;
    if(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
       BEGIN
         CREATE TABLE dbo.list_employees(id_employee VARCHAR(36), first_name VARCHAR(50), last_name VARCHAR(50), contact VARCHAR(255))
       END

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
      SET @insert_statement = 'INSERT INTO list_employees SELECT '''+@id_employee +''', '''+@first_name +''', '''+@last_name +''','''+ @contact +''''
     exec(@insert_statement ) 

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursore INTO @id_employee , @first_name , @last_name , @contact ;
        END 
        CLOSE cursore;
        DEALLOCATE cursore;
    END;
```

Comment: Why are you **injecting** the parameters and not *parametrising* them? If you *parametrise* your parameters, you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: Though, why are you even using Dynamic SQL here, when the only thing you inject are parameters? Your statement should just be `INSERT INTO dbo.list_employees VALUES (@id_employee,@first_name,@last_name,@contact);` there is no need for the `@insert_statement` variable, nor the (bad habit of using) `EXEC (@SQL)` syntax.

Comment: And why are you using a cursor for inserts like this? This entire procedure should be converted to a single insert statement. The whole bit about dropping the table and then recreating it is rather silly. Just truncate the table and populate it.

Comment: Perhaps instead of a procedure what you really want is a view?

Comment: Also your procedure is called `list_employees` and your table is also called... `list_employees`?

Comment: you are right, I just needed to write the insert statement without the Dynamic SQL, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's cover off why what you have isn't working; this is because you are **injecting** values that should be parameters. Specifically these 2 lines are the cause:

```sql
SET @insert_statement = 'INSERT INTO list_employees SELECT '''+@id_employee +''', '''+@first_name +''', '''+@last_name +''','''+ @contact +''''
exec(@insert_statement )
```

There are, in truth, 2 bad habits here:

1. injection of non-sanitised values (a huge security vulnerability)
2. Use of `EXEC(@SQL)` syntax, rather than `sys.sp_executesql`, meaning you *can't* parametrise your statement.

If you parametrise your statement, then the problem you have goes away:

```sql
SET @insert_statement = 'INSERT INTO dbo.list_employees (id_employee,first_name,last_name,contact) VALUES (@id_employee,@first_name,@last_name,@contact);';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @insert_statement, N'@id_employee VARCHAR(36),@first_name VARCHAR(50),@last_name VARCHAR(50),@contact VARCHAR(255)', @id_employee,@first_name,@last_name,@contact;
```

Of course, this poses the question of why use dynamic SQL at all, there's nothing dynamic about the statement. It's not that the table might not exist prior to the execution, as if a table doesn't exist the validation can be deferred by the engine, and you `CREATE` the table in the same scope. Perhaps the definition of the table is changing? I *hope* not.

As also mentioned, however, the `CURSOR` isn't really required here. Although you state you are practicing them, there are *very few* times that they are ever needed, and changing something like this to use an RBAR `CURSOR` will be terrible for performance. You really should be using a set based `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.list_employees (id_employee,first_name,last_name,contact)
SELECT TOP (20)
       e.id,
       e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       c.contact
FROM dbo.employees e
     JOIN dbo.contacts c ON c.fk_employee= e.id
ORDER BY e.id;
```

Or, better yet, use a `VIEW` as Sean demonstrates in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235880/2029983).

Answer (score 2):

Since your code drops an existing table and then recreates it I suspect this procedure is an odd way of getting the "current top 20". Instead of using a cursor and all sorts of hassle this would be massively simplified to use a view. There is no need to constantly drop a table and repopulate it.

Here is what your view might look like.

```
create or alter view list_employees as
    SELECT TOP(20) d.id
        , d.first_name
        , d.last_name
        , cd.contact
    FROM employees d 
    JOIN contacts cd ON cd.fk_employee = d.id
    ORDER BY d.id;
```

Comment: I don't need a view, as I wrote I was just practicing with cursors and I just don't have to use Dynamic SQL

Comment: I would stop practicing with cursors. They are the spawn of evil. Instead start practicing how to write set based code. Learning set based queries will serve you far better.